# Intent to display some text?

Tags: android

I am using an intent to display a web page on a button click:

```
link1Btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
{
      public void onClick(View v)
  {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.youtube.com" );
       startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
  }
```

Is there a way to use an intent to display some text?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific on what you mean by "some text".

Answer (score 0):

**sending side**

```
 linkbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            Intent n = new Intent(youractivity.this,secondactivity.class);
            n.putExtra("param", "your string to pass");
            startActivity(n);   
        }
    });
```

**Receiving side**

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{
   String val  = extras.getString("param");
       tv.setText(val);
}
```